# Git server auto sync to another location server

Tags: git

I am using git server in ubuntu. I have another server in other place. Now I have to sync the file between this two git servers every day morning 6 am. how to do this one. because i am new one for git.

Comment: Why? would it not be better to have one git server and commit and push to that from 2 locations?

Comment: no. we have to plane to auto sync. because we have more than two server. user only push the local server. then every day we need to sync to another location servers. like a backup

Comment: i search the google. It suggest mirroring. but i didn't understand

Comment: Take a look at this https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Comment: Is the second server only for backup or do you have people checking out from / pushing to it as well? Is this a one-way sync?

Comment: it is not one way sync. if we consider two servers, both server data want to synch based on time.

Answer (score 2):

First, make a mirrored clone of the repository on the second server. A mirrored repository is one that looks exactly like its origin, rather than having remote branches corresponding to the ones in the origin. `git help clone` explains it better than I do:

> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies --bare. Compared to --bare, --mirror not only maps local branches of the source to local
>              branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these
>              refs are overwritten by a git remote update in the target repository.

So make your mirror:

```
git clone --mirror git://example.com/repo.git
```

Then all your cron job has to do is a `git fetch`:

```
cd repo.git
git fetch
```

The repo remembers where it was cloned from and fetches from there by default.